# Angular Schema Form custom synchronous validation not working at the very onset

Tags: angular-schema-form

I am using the below Schema and Form. Please check the JSFiddle below for how this behaves. I'd like for form to be Not Valid when I say yes to "Do I have to agree" but then did not check the "agree" and clicked the save button. Looks like I first have to select the agree and then un-select it for the validation message to appear.
http://jsfiddle.net/mutharasus/Ljp7bhgn/

```
$scope.schema = {
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "doIHaveToAgree": {"type": "boolean"},
    "agree": { "type": "boolean" }
   },
   "required": ["doIHaveToAgree"]
};


$scope.form = [
    {
        "key":"doIHaveToAgree",
        "title": "Do I have to agree",
        "type":"radios-inline",
        "titleMap":[{"value":true,"name":"Yes"},{"value":false,"name":"No"}]
    },
    {
    "key": "agree",
    "condition": "model.doIHaveToAgree",
    "validationMessage": {
        "agreeRequired": "You have to agree"
    },
      "$validators": {
          "agreeRequired": function(value){
              return value;
          }
      }
  },
  {
    "type": "submit",
    "title": "Save"
  }
];
```

This appears to be as a result of https://github.com/Textalk/angular-schema-form/issues/388

I do not want to make "agree" required since that would only work for the UI. On the server side the schema validation would fail when "doIHaveToAgree" is false.

Is there any way for me to trigger the `$validate()` on the field manually since the `$validate()` is not being invoked as part of the `schemaFormValidate` event?

Comment: I agree with your point that this is a result of the mentioned bug. Using custom validator you are checking the `required` functionality.So,  I have found some work around for your issue, Please check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ljp7bhgn/12/).

Comment: Thanks. Your solution does work but unfortunately I am not able to update my schema for this because I have a conditional logic for when the agree check box appears. So if I were to update the schema like you suggested then my server side schema validation would fail on scenarios where agree was not really required.

Comment: Let me tell you what I understood. Say, on selecting some condition you are displaying the `agree` checkbox. if that condition is not reached then `agree` checkbox wouldn't be displayed and hence it is not the required one. Am I correct ??

Comment: Yes. I updated my fiddle as well as my question above to clarify.